# Playwright: Can I get the device being used so I can follow a different route in a test?

Tags: playwright

I've got my suite to run against two different browsers by setting my config file to use a desktop and mobile device:

```
  {
      name: 'firefox - Desktop',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'Mobile Safari - Portrait',
      use: {
        ...devices['iPhone 12'],
      },
    },
```

Is it possible to get which device is being used in a test? The site being tested is responsive so things like images might be visible on desktop but not on mobile so I need a way to put a condition in my test to assert it's visible if desktop but not if mobile.

Update:
For anyone else who asks this, you can use isMobile https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-is-mobile

e.g.

```
test('MyTest', async ({ page, isMobile }) => {
```

// isMobile returns a boolean depending if a mobile browser / device is used.
}

Comment: Hi, probably this can help https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testinfo#test-info-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-is-mobile

This can be called in a test and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The information for the project currently being tested can be accessed through `test.info().project`. For example:

```js
    test('My test', async ({ page }) => {
        let projectName = test.info().project.name;
    })
```

More information is available from https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-info