# Playwright - access isMobile in browserContext

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I would like to determine during runtime if the browser type is mobile (based on viewport size) or not. According to the [Playwright Documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-is-mobile)

browserContext has an optional boolean ***isMobile***  that could allow returning this information, but i cannot seem to find a way to access it.

For example,

```
page.context().browser().browserType().name() will return the browser name that the current test is running on
```

but:

```
page.context().browser().browserType().isMobile() won't work as the function does not exit
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73989840/1913729), you can get the value like so: `test('MyTest', async ({ page, isMobile }) => {`

Comment: Thanks @blex, I need to access the value at the page object level (outside of the tests) where certain functions would determine which route to go - mobile or desktop. Your solution would work if i pass in isMobile in the test declaration test('MyTest', async ({ page, isMobile }) and then, for example, i do something like await page.loginFlow(isMobile) in the test, but i am trying to find a way to access it directly where loginFlow is declared.

Comment: I answered a similar question here, passing isMobile when creating pageobject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77126554/11083750 - does that help?